# Display text/label on Nodes, D3.js force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I don't understand how to display text on my nodes 
I tried several times but didn't work, please help me to solve it

I'm not familiar with D3.js at all but I need to visualize a graph for my project, and I need this additional feature (display label) on the nodes

Here is the input file:

```
{
"nodes":[
{"name":"A","group":0},
{"name":"B","group":1},
{"name":"C","group":2},
{"name":"D","group":3},
{"name":"E","group":4}

],
"links":[
{"source":0,"target":1,"value":11},
{"source":0,"target":2,"value":11},
{"source":1,"target":2,"value":21},
{"source":1,"target":3,"value":21},
{"source":1,"target":4,"value":21},
{"source":2,"target":3,"value":21},
{"source":2,"target":4,"value":21},
{"source":3,"target":4,"value":11}
]
}
```

D3.js Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // use print_graph() method to output graph vertices
    main_graph();

    var width = 700,
        height = 300;


    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)

        .linkDistance(150)
        .size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

    d3.json("input.json", function(error, graph) {
        force
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .links(graph.links)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
                return Math.sqrt(d.value);
            });

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            // size of nodes
            .attr("r", 20)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return color(d.group);
            })
            .call(force.drag);



        //I'm stuck here
        var texts = svg.selectAll("text.label")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name;
            });

        /*
             // 1st trying
             var text = svg.selectAll("text")
                     .data(graph.node)
                     .enter().append("text")
                     .attr("fill","white")
                      .text(function (d) {return d.name; });
        */

        // another trying
        //node.append("text")
        //.text(function(d) { return d.name; });


        node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name;
            });

        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            node.attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return d.y;
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you make something like a fiddle?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292)?

Comment: Thank you, I've seen the example and it's work

Comment: If anyone can tell me where the error in the code above, I'll be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How you are adding the `text` is fine but in your `force.on("tick", function() {})` handler you don't position the them:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
    texts.attr("x", function(d) { //<-- NEED TO POSITION THESE TOO
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
 });
```

Here's your code [fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/dfBnsQukFuFDLuao1j2c?p=preview).